# Possible cardinalities of the union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

So the question is:

> What are the possible cardinalities of the union of the two sets $A$
>   (where $[A] = 5$) and $B$ (where $[B] = 9$)

So, the smallest $[A \cup B]$ is when all elements of $A$ are also elements of $B$.
Then, $[A \cup B]$ in this case is:

> (those 5 similar elements) + (the remaining 4 in B) = 9

And the largest $[A \cup B]$ is when no element of A is in B 
Then, $[A \cup B]$ in this case is:

> $[A] + [B] = 14$

Then the possible cardinalities of $[A \cup B]$ is:

> 9, 10, ... , 14

I don't understand how my reasoning is incorrect.
My book says that 6 is a possible cardinality.
The only explanation I could think of is that one or both of the sets has duplicate elements. But, wouldn't the cardinality of a set with duplicate elements be the amount of unique elements?

Edit: I actually worded the question for the sake of my explanation. The actual question is:

> We form the union of a set with 5 elements and a set with 9 elements. Which of the following numbers can we get as the cardinality of the union: 4, 6, 9, 10, 14, 20

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, so either the book has an error or you are misinterpreting what it says.  What is the exact phrasing of the question in the book and its solution?

Comment: To me, it seems that your reasoning is still right given the wording of the question.

Comment: Normally $\cup$ is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ and $\bigcup$ is used in things like $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$.  I changed $\bigcup$ to $\cup$ in this question. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you. Today I learned!

Comment: I've seen cardinalities denoted by absolute value signs, as in $|A|$, but I don't recall ever before seeing square brackets used for that, as in $[A]$. $\qquad$

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that. I'm new to set theory. Thank you again!

Comment: This is question **1.2.12** in Lovász & Pelikán & Vesztergombi's [Discrete Mathematics](https://doi.org/10.1007/b97469).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct.  More simply, $6$ can't possibly be the cardinality of the union, since the union must contain at least as many elements as $B$!  It seems that the book just has an error in the solution.